# How to improve performance of UITableView loading hundreds of Images from Documents Directory?

Tags: ios, uiimage, uikit

I'm loading a list of image files from the Documents Directory and setting them inside a Custom UITableViewCell, however, my previous efforts have either been too memory heavy, or resulting in bad UITableView scrolling performance.

In each of these methods, I load the image into container class, and then an array.

What I have tried:

- [UIImage+ImmediateLoad](https://gist.github.com/takuma104/259357) (A Custom UIImage category that loads an image from a file path and loads it straight into the memory. This results in 60FPS scrolling, but crashing of the application if the user has over 100+ Albums.)
- The MPMediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork method. (This however, causes the scrolling frame rate to drop dramatically. I don't think this directly loads the images into memory (correct me if I'm wrong).)
- Passing the file path to the UITableViewCell itself, and having it load the image. This results in slow scrolling too, but also does not throttle memory.

These images can be up to 1MB each.

In short (and I know I'm asking for a lot), I'm asking for a way to load images for the Documents directory that isn't too hard on memory, and scrolls smoothly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another strategy is to have an ordered list of image paths and a matching mutable array. Say the user is at location 0. Load images say 0-10 in the array. As the user scrolls always keep the last n images, free older ones (put NSNull in the mutable array), and prefetch the next n. Where this struggles is during active scrolling, sinc too much background work can cause scroll stutter. However it reduces memory pressure by only keeping a relatively small set of data in memory at any given time.

Other thoughts. You can save UIImageViews instead of just the images. Instead of tossing out of range images, throw them in a NSCache.

If all else fails you can do what PhotoScrollerNetwork does, and prerender the images in one massive file, then use mmap to grab the pixels for any given image and quickly create a a CGImage. Here you trade off the file system space for speed.

Comment: The bottom line is of course there is no perfect solution - you have many tradeoffs to make and its never perfect. What I would really focus on is the question: "How will the typical customer use this?", and not try to solve the idiot who is scrolling like a madman. Also, you might want to think about solving a different problem: that is, a more fluid solution would be to offer the user a scrolling list of thumbnails (which you can create beforehand and cache easily), and only show the larger images when one is selected. Assuming jpg images, the decompression time/space of a 1M image is huge.

Comment: Actually I'm using png. Does that make a difference?